# joomla phoca gallery pagination linear css fixing issue

Tags: joomla, gallery

I want that "start", "next", etc buttons should be linear. Already break down in Joomla Phoca gallery pagination. See this image:

http://srajib.info/phoca/phoca-3.png

CSS

```
#phocagallery .pgcenter, #phocagallery-upload .pgcenter, #phocagallery-subcategory-creating .pgcenter {text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="pgcenter">
<div class="pginline">
</div>
<div class="sectiontablefooter" style="margin: 0pt 10px; display: inline;">
....
....
```

Comment: what do you mean "should be linear"? what are they at the moment? what version of Phoca Gallery are you using?

Comment: would you also be able to provide a link to the website so we can test in Firebug?

Comment: Linear means it should be in 1 line like "< prev 1 2 3 Next >", which means left to right, not one line after another. By the way, the link is: http://srajib.info/eed/index.php/gallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this to your phocagallery.css, it will solve the problem:

```
ul.pagination li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    list-style:none
}
```

By the way, I know it's your site but just to let you know, I really dislike the EED cursor with the letters that also follow it ;)

Comment: Many Many Thanx!!! :D it works :) Can you solve "About Us" links, sublinks to be same height?? [see left links] I also agree. by the way, can u suggest some beautiful curser links that i can put here to make the site more lookrative?? http://srajib.info/eed/index.php/gallery

Comment: @user1630769 - glad it solved the problem. please mark the answer as correct. As for the about us links, you should ask a new question and provide a screenshot of some sort and more information to show exactly what you mean. For the cursor, I think you should leave it as default ;)